# How to get the postgresql headers on centos6

Tags: postgresql, postfix-mta, centos6

I am trying to compile postfix with pgsql support, which needs the postgresql headers, which should be in /usr/include/postgresql

I installed the following postgresql191 packages on my centOS-6.4

.x86_64

-devel.x86_64

-libs.x86_64

-server.x86_64

I thought the headers should be included in the -devel package, but still no headers to be seen. Which package do I need to install to get the headers?

Comment: `rpm -ql postgresql-devel` will show its list of files with full paths. Apparently headers go into `/usr/include/pgsql`, **not** `/usr/include/postgresql`

Comment: thanks the command helped. its actually in /usr/pgsql-9.1/include, go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Vérité had the right lead: rpm-ql postgresql191-devel.x86_64 showed me the files are in /usr/pgsql-9.1/include